# How to replace dataframe column values using a function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a large CSV, where I need to map the IP Protocol Column from String to there IP Protocol Number. For example TCP -> 6.

I want to use this to map the values.

```
socket.getprotobyname("TCP")
```

My first option to map all the columns is to use a dictionary and then the replace function.

```
 ip_dict = {"TCP": socket.getprotobyname("TCP"), "UDP": socket.getprotobyname("UDP")ect...}

df.replace({"proto": ip_dict})
```

But I want to use the the socket function inside the replace function but I can't find a way to get the current value to pass it as argument

```
  df["protocol"] = df["protocol"].str.replace(this*, socket.getprotobyname(this*))
```

**this** is the the current value to be replaced.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method to create a new column by apply a function to each element of a given column.

So in your case, you can do this:

```
df["protocol"] = df["protocol"].apply(socket.getprotobyname)
```

Equivalently, applying a lambda function makes it clear that you're passing every element as an argument (as you intended to do in your attempt):

```
df["protocol"] = df["protocol"].apply(lambda this: socket.getprotobyname(this))
```

Comment: df["proto"] = df["proto"].apply(lambda this: socket.getprotobyname(this))
OSError: protocol not found

Comment: sounds like one of the values in your `df['proto']` column cannot be used as an argument to `socket.getprotobyname`.

Comment: u are right, I had to make try exept and pass when the value is not a string. It runs without error but the values of the column are still the same

Comment: Is it possible that the errors even though bypassed, prevent the changes from being written to the data frame?

Comment: Yes, wrapping a try/except around the line in the answer will prevent it from executing if a value in the column is invalid (even if the others aren't). You need to either filter or replace the bad values in the dataframe prior to executing the apply method.